# US timezone conversion into EST in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My table has 3 column, id, timezone, closingTime(HH:mm 24hrs format). I am trying to convert every entry in this table in EST format. I have already created a query and it is working fine. But, the issue is I am passing -5:00, -4:00 inside the query. Is there a way sql internally handles it return me the timezone in EST format. What about the day light saving, does sql server internally handles it?

```
with est_table as (select  id,  closingTime ,
case
when timeZone='EST' THEN cast(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ),' ', closingTime, ' ','-5:00' ),100) as DATETIMEOFFSET)at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)
when timeZone='CST' THEN cast(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ),' ', closingTime, ' ','-6:00'  ),100) as DATETIMEOFFSET)at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)
when timeZone='MDT' THEN cast(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ),' ', closingTime, ' ','-7:00' ),100) as DATETIMEOFFSET)at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)
when timeZone='PST' THEN cast(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ),' ', closingTime, ' ','-8:00' ),100) as DATETIMEOFFSET)at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)
else CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )
 END  as EST 
from test_timezone
```

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE` automatically handles DST, yes, but you don't appear to be in your data; you have EST, CST, M**D**T and PST. Also, MDT (Mountain **Daylight** Time) is UTC -06:00, not -07:00 (that's MST (Mountain Standard Time)).

Comment: Also [don't do this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length): `CONVERT(VARCHAR,`

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I will make that change

Comment: @Larnu - so you are saying I dont need to manually update the UTC time. It will automatically convert it? I am not quite sure. Could you please xplain, or is there a better way to write this query?